# Full-screen background video does not autoplay

Tags: html, css, html5-video, fullpage.js

I'm making a simple web page, and I wanted the first window to have a full screen playing video. I tried to embed it like this:

```
<div class="section active">
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
<source src="videos/Space.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/Space.webm" type="video/webm"> 
Video not supported 
</video>
```

and

```
#video_background {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 69;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The first frame shows up, but it doesn't start playing. The files are in their proper location. Why could this be? I'm using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/267

You will have to make use of the callbacks `afterRender` or `afterLoad` for it.

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    afterRender: function(){
        $('#video')[0].play();
    }
});
```

Now you can find also an available example to download in the [examples folder](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples) of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="section active">
<video id="video_background" autoplay loop muted preload="auto">
<source src="videos/Space.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/Space.webm" type="video/webm"> 
Video not supported 
</video>
```